# Form onsubmit with javascript not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, forms, google-chrome, action, onsubmit

I am trying to pass a single form values on two different actions pages using javascript and I succeeded in it as Firefox, Opera and even IE is passing values on both action pages but chrome skips the 1st action page which is Paypal Process page. (I've tried two ways for this but chrome doesn't support any of it.)

> 1st Way I Tried

Here is my form starting tag: `<form onsubmit='return SubmitProcess()' id='registerAndCheckout' method='post' action=''>`

And here is the javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

function SubmitForm()
{            
    document.forms['registerAndCheckout'].action='paypal-express-checkout/process.php';
    document.forms['registerAndCheckout'].target='_blank';
    document.forms['registerAndCheckout'].submit();

    document.forms['registerAndCheckout'].action='paypal-express-checkout/course-register.php';
    document.forms['registerAndCheckout'].target='_self';
    document.forms['registerAndCheckout'].submit();

    return true;
}
</script>
```

> 2nd Way I'd tried

Here is my form starting tag: `<form onsubmit='return SubmitProcess() & SubmitForm()' id='registerAndCheckout' method='post' action=''>`

And here is the javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

function SubmitProcess()
{            
    document.forms['registerAndCheckout'].action='paypal-express-checkout/process.php';
    document.forms['registerAndCheckout'].target='_blank';
    document.forms['registerAndCheckout'].submit();            
    return true;
}
function SubmitForm()
{       
    document.forms['registerAndCheckout'].action='paypal-express-checkout/course-register.php';
    document.forms['registerAndCheckout'].target='_self';
    document.forms['registerAndCheckout'].submit();
    return true;
}
</script>
```

But if I remove the second part from the script which is:

```
document.forms['registerAndCheckout'].action='paypal-express-checkout/course-register.php';
document.forms['registerAndCheckout'].target='_self';
document.forms['registerAndCheckout'].submit();
return true;
```

Then first part of script also works in Chrome, can anyone tell me why is it so?

Comment: You can not submit a form to two addresses at once (and no, that it might have worked in one browser you tested this in means nothing). Every browser is free to _abort_ the first submission at the time a second one occurs.

Comment: @CBroe Firefox, Opera and even IE is supporting which means that it is possible to submit a form to two addresses at once.